# Bukkit PlayerInteractEvent gets registered twice

Tags: java, events, bukkit

So I've been building some EventHandlers in Bukkit and now I am stuck on this. It's probably a really dumb mistake, so forgive me for that.

What I want is the following: when I rightclick on a block, it should just put each second: `test` in chat. But it actually puts it twice each second. I've been debugging pretty much the whole code, but I'm not getting it working. In my idea it is registering twice.

*Main() class:*

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

   @Override
   public void onEnable() {
      getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Events(), this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDisable() {
   }
}
```

*Events() class:*

```
public class Events implements Listener {
   public Plugin plugin = Main.getPlugin(Main.class);

   @EventHandler
   public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
      Player player = e.getPlayer();
      Action action = e.getAction();

      if(action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
         new BukkitRunnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                   player.sendMessage("Test");
                }

         }.runTaskTimer(plugin, 1, 20);
      }

   }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `PlayerInteractEvent` calls twice is that it calls for two hands - once for `OFF_HAND` and once for `HAND`. So, to handle this event only 1 time you must check exactly hand you want:

```
if (e.getHand() == EquipmentSlot.HAND) {
    // ... Your code with test
}
```